# KMM with Java sources in common (shared) module

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

As a platform limitation we can't use Java sources with Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile.

But if Kotlin is 100% compatible with Java, why can't we use Java with Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile? I mean use it not only in Android or JVM section only, but in common section with shared code. We could write iOS apps with Java :)

Comment: Kotlin is compatible with java inside java applications but if you e.g. compile to JS, you cannot use java. Multiplatform means it should work for multiple platforms (not only JVM).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Kotlin/JVM** is indeed interoperable with Java, however KMM has two targets: Native and Android. This means that in common code you can use only dependencies which can be compiled by both the Kotlin/JVM and the Kotlin/Native compiler.

In your case, when trying to add a java dependency in your common code, Kotlin/Native will not know how to translate that to iOS.

What you can do is abstract away the JVM parts with the `expect/actual` and give an implementation for the Kotlin/Native compiler which it can understand, but you won't be able to use any Java library as it is.

Comment: what about if iam targeting only for JVM desktop and android?
how to force common main to allow JAVA (JVM Kotlin) code?